# overriding virtual event

Tags: events, inheritance, virtual

I've got the following code

```
public delegate void NotificacaoScanner(NotifScanner e);   

// interface
public interface IScanner
{
   event NotificacaoScanner onFinalLeitura;
}


// abstract class that implements the interface
public abstract class ScannerGCPerif : IScanner
{
   public virtual event NotificacaoScanner onFinalLeitura;
   {
     add { throw new NotImplementedException("Event not available for this service"); }
     remove { throw new NotImplementedException("Event not available for this service");          }
   } 
}


// concrete class that implements the abstract class
public class ScannerBurroughs : ScannerGCPerif
{
  public override event NotificacaoScanner onFinalLeitura;
}
```

Why when I subscribe the `onFinalLeitura` event of a `ScannerBurroughs` instance, it insists on execute  the event declaration of the base class (ScannerGCPerif), where the exception is?

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and I did not get an exception. Let me explain what happens:

You override the event in your concrete class, but you do not provide implementation for adding and removing event handlers so the compiler generates the following code:

```
public class ScannerBurroughs : ScannerGCPerif
{
    private NotificacaoScanner _onFinalLeitura; // Declare a private delegate

    public override event NotificacaoScanner onFinalLeitura
    {
        add { _onFinalLeitura += value; }
        remove { _onFinalLeitura -= value; }
    }
}
```

Behind the scenes it adds a private delegate and autoimplements the add / remove event accessors. The base implementation never gets called when you subscribe. Try explicitly implementing the accessors, put some breakpoints in your code and see what happens.